# using python library in .net

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

is it possible to include a library created in python/php in a .net application. In this scenario the library handles authentication for an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely possible to use a Python script with [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/).  You'll even find that it integrates very nicely with .NET 4.0's DLR.  And while 4.0 is the recommended framework, there are [versions](http://ironpython.net/download/) compatible with 2.0 and upwards, so the fact that you're using VS2008 isn't a problem.

There are some possibilities with PHP as well: [Phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/) claims to compile PHP scripts to MSIL.